# How do I debug when using full html link path in links?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I read that for many reasons its better you use full link paths between pages in my site.
The question is how can i debug and work on my local testing environment when all of the links are with full path?

(Manually replacing them is not an option...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an customizable prefix, change it for your test environment.

I don't know ASP.net, so this would be it in, say... JSP:

```
---- something.jsp --------
...
<%! public static final PREFIX = "http://pohlidame.cz/"; %>
...
<a href="<%= PREFIX %>onas">Insolvenční rejstřík</a>
...
---------------------------
```

This is quite simplistic example. In component oriented frameworks, you create the links' href value somewhere in the controller tier. That might be the case of ASP.net.

But generally, it's a simple concatenation of the prefix plus your desired "relative" location.

Comment: can you please explain, give a short example?

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute links has no impact on SEO, but is helpful in instances of site-scraping, site duplication (http/https, for example) etc.

Have you considered using relative URLs along with the **base** tag? You could then dynamically insert the current domain into the target, giving you the benefit of absolute tags along with the ease-of-use of using relative tags (on debug, staging and live sites).